# debian installation error os not found

Tags: virtual-machine, debian-installer, pxe

I need to perform a Network Install from ISO image for Debian 8.7.1 in a VM. I expect to be able to start the VM, have it boot from the image, and then start the Debian Linux installation process in the virtual machine. But the VM says Operating System not found:

[image: vm and debian 8.7]

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a [PXE boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) failure.  This is not related to [Debian Linux Network Install](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/).  They are different technologies.  The message you are seeing is invoked by your system BIOS, and likely was invoked by you from the keyboard. To do the Debian Install you probably want to disable PXE.